# android unzip folder from zip file and read content from that folder

Tags: android, image, directory, unzip

in one of my app i need to extract a zip file that have folder inside and that folder contains images it mean abc.zip=>adb(folder)=>abc.png
i want to extract image file

i used below method

```
 private boolean extractFolder(File destination, File zipFile) throws ZipException, IOException
    {
        int BUFFER = 8192;
        File file = zipFile;
        //This can throw ZipException if file is not valid zip archive
        ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(file);
//        String newPath = destination.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + FilenameUtils.removeExtension(zipFile.getName());
        String newPath = destination.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + zipFile.getName();
        //Create destination directory
        new File(newPath).mkdir();
        Enumeration zipFileEntries = zip.entries();

        //Iterate overall zip file entries
        while (zipFileEntries.hasMoreElements())
        {
            ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) zipFileEntries.nextElement();
            String currentEntry = entry.getName();
            File destFile = new File(newPath, currentEntry);
            File destinationParent = destFile.getParentFile();
            //If entry is directory create sub directory on file system
            destinationParent.mkdirs();

            if (!entry.isDirectory())
            {
                //Copy over data into destination file
                BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(zip
                        .getInputStream(entry));
                int currentByte;
                byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
                //orthodox way of copying file data using streams
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile);
                BufferedOutputStream dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER);
                while ((currentByte = is.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                    dest.write(data, 0, currentByte);
                }
                dest.flush();
                dest.close();
                is.close();
            }
        }
        return true;//some error codes etc.
    }
```

but getting `zipfolder/foldername/ (Is a directory)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
private void unzip(String src, String dest){

        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

        BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(src);
            ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream));
            ZipEntry zipEntry;

            while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null){

                String zipEntryName = zipEntry.getName();

                String name = dest.substring(dest.lastIndexOf("/")-1);

                File FileName = new File(FolderName);
                if (!FileName.isDirectory()) {
                    try {
                        if (FileName.mkdir()) {
                        } else {
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                File file = new File(FolderName+"/" +zipEntryName);

                if (file.exists()){

                } else {
                    if(zipEntry.isDirectory()){
                        file.mkdirs();
                    }else{
                        byte buffer[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream, BUFFER_SIZE);
                        int count;

                        while ((count = zipInputStream.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1) {
                            bufferedOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }

                        bufferedOutputStream.flush();
                        bufferedOutputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            zipInputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Try This code it's working for me.